# Error when using unnest() following pivot_wider() in R

Tags: r, pivot, reshape2, unnest

I have a dataset that I am trying to reshape as wider

The original dataset is something like this

#df

```
Cell_line       Gene     AF
COLO320         MYC      0.5
COLO320         KRAS     0.4
H524            MYC      0.6
H524            KRAS     0.5
```

Expected is something like this:

```
**Cell_line** **MYC** **KRAS**
COLO320         0.5      0.4
H524            0.6      0.5
```

I don't want to lose any of my values so what I did is the following:

```
df1 = df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Gene, values_from = AF, values_fn = list)
```

However I was getting a "dbl" as a list in the column values so I added a `unnest()`:

```
df1 = df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Gene, values_from = AF, values_fn = list)  %>% unnest(cols = everything())
```

However, I am getting the following error example :
Error in `unnest()`:

> In row 8, can't recycle input of size 4 to size 2.

Anybody knows what is the solution?

My aim at the end is to reshape the data wider without losing the values.

Comment: just use `df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Gene, values_from = AF)`

Comment: I did so. It still gives me "dbl" in the column values, which is why I went to use unnest

Comment: What are you expecting other than "dbl"? That just means the column contains numbers stored as doubles which basically means a number with a decimal point. It's not clear what you are trying to do that you cannot do with the output suggested by Mael. Maybe update your example to make it clear what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is caused by the fact that the data that I want to spread / pivot wider has duplicate identifiers. So at the end I am not getting the values and I don't want to remove the values

Comment: Then please update your example to accurately reflect your real situation.